# When I resize my browser windows, my Images moves when they should stay together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

When I resize my browser windows, all my images moves

What I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLhWv.jpg

I have tried to use Relative, Absolute and to use a JavaScript code to resize the images

The HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html><head>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- jQuery library -->



<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="myDiv" class="text-center mydiv">
    <img class="img-fluid background" src="assets/images/Background.png">
    <img class="img-fluid arm" src="assets/images/image1-arm.png">
  </div>
<script src="js/main.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" crossorigins="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```css
.img-fluid{
    max-width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
.img-fluid.arm{
    max-width: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 510px;
    top: -80px;}
.img-fluid.background{
    position: absolute;
}
.mydiv{
    position: relative;
    top: 110px;
}
```

The images should remain fixed together

What I want :https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFzyy.jpg

Website link to test: http://calendar.followthesunquiz.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the context these images will be used in? Can the combined area around the images have a fixed height and width?

Because `position: absolute` takes items out of the document flow, if you look at your `<div id="myDiv" class="text-center mydiv">` in the inspector it has 0px height and width, because it doesn't know about the absolutely positioned items within it.

If you give it a fixed height and width that are the same, for example:

```
.mydiv {
  position: relative;
  top: 110px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

You can position the `.img-fluid.arm` image relative to that:

```
.img-fluid.arm {
    max-width: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 68%;
    top: -10%;
}
```

Those values got it to work for me. Percentages are generally better than hard-coded pixel values, because, for example, if you want this combined image to scale at different screen sizes, you can increase or decrease `.my-div`'s width/height (making sure that they are always a square) and you shouldn't have to change the percentages on the position for `.img-fluid-arm`

Comment: that fixed it, I never realised that my-div had 0px dimensions, I thought it took the dimentions of the content

Thanks you very much both